# Difference between WebPage and Article, when to use one over the other?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

What is the difference between `WebPage` and `Article` for rich snippets and when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An article stands alone. A webpage is a complete page that can include many articles and non-articles.

https://schema.org/WebPage

> A web page. Every web page is implicitly assumed to be declared to be of type WebPage

https://meta.schema.org/Article

> An article, such as a news article or piece of investigative report.